# How to get the position of more than one word in a list

Tags: python-2.7

```
import re
word = input("Type a word")
sentence = ['example',ahhu','example']
Positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, sentence)]
print(Positions)
```

the output is

```
Positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, sentence)]

  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 219, in finditer
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: any reason why you don't  have the extra `'` in `sentence = ['example',ahhu','example']`.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when typing the word? What do you get if you give `abc` as an input when prompted? Do you get a `NameError`?

Answer (score 2):

`re.finditer()` expects a string/buffer as a second parameter but a list is passed, raising this exception.

**Edit:**
If you just want to get the positions of elements in `sentence` list that are equal to `word` you can also do :

```
>>> sentence = ['example', 'spam', 'egg', 'bacon', 'spam', 'spam']
>>> word = 'spam'
>>> positions = [i for i, string in enumerate(sentence) if string == word]
>>> positions
[1, 4, 5]
```

Your example would work if you replace `sentence` with a string. Note that `word` is actually a regex pattern in this case:

```
>>> sentence = "example spam egg example spam spam"
>>> import re
>>> word = 'spam'
>>> positions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, sentence)]
>>> print(positions)
[8, 25, 30]
```

Comment: Actually this is right, it triggers exactly the same error the OP described, although it's not the only error in the code. I'll update my answer, and upvote yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This error is triggered because a list is passed as a second argument to the `finditer()` method instead of a string, (see [Zormos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861950/zhormos)'s answer). However, this is not the only issue with the code (see below).

---

Is this indeed Python2.7? If so, you should change `input()` to `raw_input()`, because the former in Python2.x tries to evaluate the input as a Python expression.

If you, by a coincidence, type in something that is e.g. a valid variable name, `word` will not be a string, but a reference to that variable.

**Demo (using Python2.7):**

```
>>> abc = 123
>>> word = input("Enter a word: ")
Enter a word: abc
>>> print word
123
>>> word == abc
True
>>> type(word)
<type 'int'>
>>> import re
>>> re.finditer(word, ['one', 'two', 'three'])
...
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use finditer:

```
import re

string="This is an example. ahhu example"
pattern="example"

for match in re.finditer(pattern,string):
    print "%s: %s" % (match.start(), match.group())
```